# target and append to a specific DOM element on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Thanks for letting me use you as a resource. I am making a blog page with different comments that share the same class, and they all have reply buttons that share a class. When the reply button is clicked a modal pops up where the user can enter in his/her reply, and when the post reply is clicked the reply should post to the specific comment. I'm having a hard time targeting the path to that specific comment. I know that the "this" keyword comes into play but I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly, also I was reading up on .attr() and think I might need it here somewhere. I'd like to get it working so that someone could come along and reply to a reply as well, and maybe even "push" the replies into a JSON template and append that way but that's more than I know how to do at this point. Even if you don't give me a full solution letting me know what I need to read up on would also help!
Thanks!

```
    //Reply button function to show modal//////////////////////////////////
        sabio.page.handlers.replyButtonClickToShowModal = function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#myModal').modal();
            console.log("reply button is firing");
        };

        $(".replyButton").on('click', sabio.page.handlers.replyButtonClickToShowModal);

        //Get reply from modal form and append to correct comment//////////////////////////////////////
        sabio.page.handlers.submitReplyButtonClick = function () {
            var clickedLink = $(this).closest(".comment.mediaclearfix");
            var replyTitle = $('#addReplyTitle').val();
            var replyEmail = $('#addReplyEmail').val();
            var replyContent = $('#addReplyContent').val();
            var replyFormat = '<br> <div class="comment-avatar media-left"> <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="avatar">' +
           '</div><div class="comment-content media-body clearfix"> <div class="comment-avatar media-left"></div><h3 class="media-heading">' +
           replyTitle + '</h3> <div class="comment-meta">By ' + replyEmail + '</div> <div class="comment-body"> <p>'
           + replyContent + '</p><a href="#" class="replyButton">' +
           '<i class="fa fa-reply"> </i> Reply </a> </div> </div>';
            clickedLink.append(replyFormat);
            console.log("submit reply function is firing");
            $('#myModal').dialog('close');
        };


        $('.btn.btn-success.cmdAddComment').on('click', sabio.page.handlers.submitReplyButtonClick);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are almost 99% correct in your approach. The only error I can see is in following statement:

```
var clickedLink = $(this).closest(".comment.mediaclearfix");
```

This is not going to work, as here `this` reference is of `submit` button present on modal dialog. So we need to modify this little bit as follows:

**Note:** Following code change will work on assumption that; at a time user can open single modal popup to submit their reply.

```
       //Reply button function to show modal//////////////////////////////////
        sabio.page.handlers.replyButtonClickToShowModal = function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#myModal').data("clickedLinkRef", $(this));  //saving the clicked link ref for future use
            $('#myModal').modal();
            console.log("reply button is firing");
        };
```

Now in the `submit` button handler we will fetch the saved clicked link reference to target the appropriate "comment".

```
$(".replyButton").on('click', sabio.page.handlers.replyButtonClickToShowModal);

//Get reply from modal form and append to correct comment//////////////////////////////////////
sabio.page.handlers.submitReplyButtonClick = function () {

    var clickedLink = $('#myModal').data("clickedLinkRef").closest(".comment.mediaclearfix"); //fetching the saved clicked link reference

    var replyTitle = $('#addReplyTitle').val();
    var replyEmail = $('#addReplyEmail').val();
    var replyContent = $('#addReplyContent').val();
    var replyFormat = '<br> <div class="comment-avatar media-left"> <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="avatar">' +
   '</div><div class="comment-content media-body clearfix"> <div class="comment-avatar media-left"></div><h3 class="media-heading">' +
   replyTitle + '</h3> <div class="comment-meta">By ' + replyEmail + '</div> <div class="comment-body"> <p>'
   + replyContent + '</p><a href="#" class="replyButton">' +
   '<i class="fa fa-reply"> </i> Reply </a> </div> </div>';
    clickedLink.append(replyFormat);
    console.log("submit reply function is firing");
    $('#myModal').dialog('close');
};


$('.btn.btn-success.cmdAddComment').on('click', sabio.page.handlers.submitReplyButtonClick);
```

I hope this will help you to achieve your goal.